# Retrofit2 stream server events

Tags: android, retrofit, networkonmainthread

I'm trying to stream an API in Android with retrofit.

```
@Streaming
@GET("stream/meter")
Observable<ResponseBody> streamMetersStatus();
```

My source code is

```
 Observable<ResponseBody> observable = ApiClientHelper.getClient().streamMetersStatus();
 observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                    try {
                        responseBody.string();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("e", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });
```

But it throwing networkOnMainThreadException. I also tried to create a new thread for observeOn but it doesn't work. Could someone public an example for streaming a json with retrofit2 in Android?

Comment: did you add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes, i am able to use GET, POST, etc. The problem is that I don't know how to use streaming in Android